# FileService was not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, service

On my stackblitz i have weird issue. Console telling me "FileService was not defined". In my opinion everything should work. Can you tell me whats wrong [there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybu1xz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to inject the service and remove declare.

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class FileService implements IFileService
   ```
2. Add fileservice to providers array in main.ts.

   ```
   import {CdkDragDropSortingExample, FileService} from './app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting- example';
   providers: [
   FileService,
   { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' } },
   ]
   ```
3. Move fileservice implementation to a new file if possible.